# tkinter grid- open but it's blank

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

So i have been building a grid style layout to be filled by the picamera. I have the camera running, the grid window opening but i seem to be missing why the images are not filling into a grid. I believe this error is in my main "grid" class but i am not sure, my eyes hurt from looking at the screen.
This is the code so far:

```
import sys
import time
import picamera
from PIL import Image
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import os
import glob
import PIL
import ImageTk


camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (100, 100)     
camera.AWB_MODES
camera.EXPOSURE_MODES
time.sleep(2)


print ('camera on')


for i in range(10):
    camera.capture("/home/pi/Pictures/image_%i.jpeg" %(i,))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('taking img')
    if i == 10:
        break

print('making grid')
class Grid(tk.Frame):
    def _init_(self,parent):
        Tkinter.TK.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        grid.pack()
        self.grid.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(row=0, column=0, weight=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(row=0, column=0, weight=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.initialize()
        print('initialize')

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        for row in range(4):
            for column in range(4):   
                for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join("/home/pi/Pictures/",'*.jpeg')):
                    image = PIL.Image.open(infile)
                    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
                    label= Label(image=photo)
                    label.image=photo
                    label.pack()

    print('come on window COMPLETE')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app =Grid(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

I have been hunting the problem using print commands. but they have only pointed to the "Print initialize" not displaying. If you have a minute i would love some help.

Comment: Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's a lot of code in your question that is unrelated to creating a grid.

Comment: The method name is `__init__` (with two underscores on each side), not `_init_` (one underscore on each side)

Comment: did you notice that the statement `print('initialize')` is never getting called? If you correct `__init__` to have two underscores you will then get an error trying to initialize a `Frame` instance with the `Tk` constructor....

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I am now able to make a column( or row) of images down the left of my window... just a little more to go..